References to study Clifford algebras
I am studying Clifford algebras from the Fulton and Harris book in the context of representations of Lie algebras. Can someone suggest alternative sources which are more comprehensible than F & H? The problem with F&H I faced is that the authors are reluctant to give some more details in the proofs.

Could you give some examples of what is not detailed enough or what you have trouble with? It would help for finding a text that suits you best.

For example in lemma 20.3 authors provide three proofs. In all three cases they provide little detail.

Only two of the six books I checked give an explicit proof that you can generate a basis for the entire Clifford algebra from an orthogonal vector basis:

Ian Porteous in Clifford Algebras and the Classical Groups, Theorem 15.10. Note that what is usually called a "Clifford algebra" nowadays is called a "universal Clifford algebra" by Porteous.
Larry Grove in Classical Groups and Geometric Algebra, Theorem 8.12. This is "geometric algebra" in the sense of Emil Artin, not the popular rebranding of Clifford algebra.

